# How to extract a substring from a PWSTR in C++

Tags: c++, windows, string, credential-providers

I'm currently modifying a credential provider for Windows 7, in C++. The Windows SDK requires use of PWSTR.

I've hit a problem where the username is sometimes being passed as DOMAIN\username and sometimes as domain.tld\username and sometimes just username. What I'd like to do is extract the username from this, and only take the substring after the slash.

I'm new to C++ and none of the string functions appear to work with PWSTR. I've tried a few conversions to wchar_t* but it's still not getting me anywhere.

How can this be achieved?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
PWSTR GetUserName(PWSTR pszUser)
{
   PWSTR pszLastSlash = wcsrchr(pszUser, L'\\');
   return pszLastSlash ? pszLastSlash + 1 : pszUser;
}
```

Note this doesn't do a separate memory allocation - the thing you return is the pointer to the part of the string beginning after the last slash.  If you were to do a proper "substring" operation like you might see in higher-level objects (instead of just taking `len - i` starting at offset `i`) you'd have to do a copy (or somehow track that you're only considering a smaller length).

Comment: Huh, even better than `wstring` if you pull out a function like `wcsrchr`.

Comment: @chris - Well, you could probably also write `wcsrchr` in about 3 lines - `PWSTR wcsrchr(PWSTR s, WCHAR c) { PWSTR r = NULL; while (*s) { if (*s == c) r = s; ++s } return r; }` - but I guess my point is the C style (as opposed to C++ or higher-level) of string manipulation lends well to this sort of thing, where you do things with fewer copies.  Personally I'm a fan of fewer copies.

Comment: @asveikau, Definitely on both points. Some more complex operations could prove my post to be of more use, but for things as simple as this, the non-converting, simple functions work better.

Comment: For a short solution that does exactly what the OP wants, one upvote isn't enough imo. @Fluidgroup, Remember this when you get enough rep to upvote answers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `std::string` for wide-character strings. Use `std::wstring` instead. `PWSTR` is a `wchar_t *`, and where `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char>`, `std::wstring` is `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`. Using that, you should be able to accomplish what you could converting a `char *` to `std::string` and manipulating it. You can see that both are similar and have the same functions etc. [on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

From there, all that needs to be done is something like the following:

```
wchar_t chars[] = L"abc";
std::wstring ws = chars;
std::wstring sub = ws.substr (0, 2); 
std::wcout << sub.c_str(); //should print 'ab'
```